# Creating WebAPI models using dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

In my controller I have the action:

```
public void Post(NewCustomerModel model)
{
    model.Save();
}
```

and the model:

```
public class NewCustomerModel
{
    private readonly CustomerRepository repository;

    public NewCustomerModel(CustomerRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        var customer = new Customer(Name);

        repository.Save(customer);
    }
}
```

I want this model to be instantiated using the IoC-container that I have configured and the `Name` property should be set by reading the values from the request.

I managed to get the IoC-container to instantiate the model by creating a custom `IModelBinder`:

```
public class MyCustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly IComponentContext componentContext;

    public EntityModelBinder(IComponentContext componentContext)
    {
        this.componentContext = componentContext;
        this.modelType = modelType;
    }

    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        object model = componentContext.Resolve(bindingContext.ModelType);
        bindingContext.Model = model;
        return true;
    }
}
```

This works fine, the repository is being injected into the model. After this I expect the WebAPI framework to take over and set the public properties, but it doesn't: the `Name` property is null. If I'm not using this model binder and use the default WebAPI framework, the `Name` property is set, so there is nothing wrong with the request-to-model mapping.

How can I make this work?

Comment: You can move the `Save` method out of the `NewCustomerModel` class to the controller itself and have a dependency on `CustomerRepository` in the controller. This way the `NewCustomerModel` does not need the `CustomerRepository` dependency.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief the controller is not responsible for these things. It is the model.

Comment: What I am suggesting is splitting data and behavior, i.e., putting data into data-only objects and behavior into behavior only objects. DI works best this way. If you want to delegate this into a behavior-only object other than the controller, then that is fine. If this is against the MVC pattern (I am not sure if it is or if it is not), then the MVC pattern is not DI friendly.

Comment: When applying SRP to MVC/WebAPI then the model is the place to put the behavior and let the controller be responsible for the page flow. Real MVC frameworks can handle this, but unfortunately Microsoft's implementations of these things are not DI friendly. This is a problem with most Microsoft frameworks and libraries.